# What is the difference between L"the following:" and "the following:"

Tags: c++, unicode

Are there any differences between the two? Both compiles with vs2013.

CStringW str1 = "the following:";
CString str2 = L"the following:";

The strings are from afxstr: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx

I understand that the variant without L is casted via the appropriate cast operator but what problems can arise from using the form without L while I do NOT use any unicode characters between the quotation marks. Is this a good programming practice to use L"" even when you don't plan to use non-unicode chars or is there more to it?

edit: maybe I realized the answer. Is the main problem is that without L, I suffer the performance hit of calling an unnecessary operator method? But are both gives the same, correct result?

Answer (score 2):

You create a wide string literal using the `L` macro. Without the `L` its just a narrow string. Also check your project settings. Are you building it as a Unicode project?
Rather than use the `L` I would recommend using the `_T()` macro which expands to `L` only if your project is being built as Unicode

Take a look at this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx) too

So in other words if you want your string to be always Unicode then use the `L`

**update:**
I would recommend

```
CString str1 = _T("the following");
```

and build your project as Unicode if you want your string to be expanded to a wide string

Comment: +1 for the reference links. Like @a3f said L is not a macro, but just a prefix used for wide strings. Prefixing string with L modifier makes the string a wide char which is needed for Unicode strings. However having _T() or _TEXT() is preferred since it will switch between MBCS and Unicode mode strings as required.

Comment: `L""` is not a macro, it is a language feature. `_T()` and `CString`, afaic, are not included in the 'standard' headers. This may be a problem for certain platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`"the following:"`'s type is `const char*` while the `L"the following`'s one is `const wchar_t*`. Depending on what you do with the second literal, you may be implicitly casting, calling overloaded versions of certain functions, cause templates to specialise for the `wchar_t` rather than the `char` type or have your code fail to compile (narrowing and implicit casts are not always allowed). Note that casting from `wchar_t` to `char` (implicitly or explicitly) is considered narrowing, since a `char` is typically 1 byte while the size of a `wchar_t` is always greater. As far as I remember, it is implementation-specific whether a `char` should be `signed` or `unsigned`; it could be then that casting from `wchar_t` to `char` does not always yields the expected results even for ascii subset of the latter - you have to check the standard for such things. Then, if you go for the `L` type of literals your program will also require more memory. As always in the world of C++, you pay for what you use, so if *don't really need unicode characters, don't use `wchar_t`*.

Comment: +1 for "if don't really need unicode characters, don't use wchar_t". [Generic Text Data Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se784sk6.aspx)

Comment: *Technically*, the types of the string literals are closer to (but not exactly the same as) `const char[]` and `const wchar_t[]`. They are actually *compiler-defined types*, which happen to degrade to `const char*` and `const wchar_t*` when needed.